# Solving for variables equal to sum of encodings

Tags: algorithm, math

The problem is from [here](http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/feng.hao/files/OpenVote_IET.pdf)

> A preferred way to deal with multiple candidates is to use the
>   method because of Baudron et al. [16]: suppose that we have
>   n voters, choose m so that m is the smallest integer such that
>   2^m > n. Now a vote for candidate 1 is encoded as 2^0
>   , for
>   candidate 2 as 2^m, for candidate 3 is 2^(2*m) and so on. In
>   other words, redefine (1) as
>
> Tabulation is much as before: `Π (g^xi*yi)*g^vi = g^Σvi`. The
>   votes are summed and the super-increasing nature of the
>   encoding ensures that the total can unambiguously be
>   resolved into the totals for the candidates. Hence,
>   `Σvi = 2^0 * c1 + 2^m * c2 + ... + 2^(k-1)m * ck` where `c1` to `ck`
>   are the counts of votes for the `k` candidates correspondingly.
>   As before, this resolution requires searching over possible
>   combinations, but of course pre-computation over (the more
>   likely) combinations could speed this up.

Basically given sum of v, how to find c's such that this equation is true:

[image: equation]

where k is the number of candidates and m is the smallest integer such that 2 ^ m > max # of votes.

Some things that might be useful in limiting the search space:

- max(c) = # of votes recorded
- there is a unique set of c's that equals some sum, v
- sum of c's <= # of votes recorded

Comment: Even in quite small votes you will get beyond 64 bit integers (eg a UK byelection, likely < 2^16 voters, but could be 10 candidates so you need 160 bits). Best to use some big integer library, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `2^m > n` is essential to make the formula

```
Σvi = 2^0 * c1 + 2^m * c2 + ... + 2^(k-1)m * ck
```

reversible from the sum to `ci`. You didn't specify you environment so I'll use some C-style pseudo-code

```
tmp = sum;
p = power(2,m);
for(i = 0; i< k; i++) {
    c[i] = tmp % p; // i.e. calculate reminder, often also called mod
    tmp = tmp / p;  // whole division on (big) integers
}
```

This should work because the condition `2^m > n` ensures that since `ci <= n` so transitively `ci < 2^m` and thus there can't be "overflow". Essentially the idea here is to represent vote counts as a number in a system with a huge  of `2^m` and each digit is just the count of votes for the corresponding candidate.